# Exclusion of types in typescript without unknown

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

Let's say I want to have an exclusion of
`{ value: T }`
and `{ error: Error }`

How can I do that? This way

`type MaybeExclusive<T> = { value: T } | { value?: never, error: Error }`
leaves an `unknown` option for `value` property.

Comment: That's not exclusive; unions in TypeScript are *inclusive*; if you want exclusive you'd need `{value: T, error?: never} | {value?: never, error: Error}` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mZ1nJN).  Does that fix your issue?  If so I guess I could write up an answer; if not, you might want to [edit] so that the premise of the question is correct and that you are actually using an exclusive union

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a type like `{value: {value: number}}`?  Maybe one of those `value`s should be changed to a different key to reduce confusion

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for answer, but I have to disagree, unions are exclusive, let's see e.g. [here](https://camchenry.com/blog/typescript-union-type). The exclusivity in `MaybeExclusive` is that there is a value, or error, not both.

I don't use a value property twice, there is only one layer.

Comment: That's someone's blog, not an authoritative source.  You can [see for yourself that unions are not exclusive](https://tsplay.dev/NV3Lvm).

Comment: You are right, he is right too. It can be excluded by giving the property [never](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAogDwMYBsCuBnASwDcIAeAFQD4oBeKAbyiLlwgC4pyoBfKAHwZMWOCAH4OAOwgkATgBooEGTID2MjimVqeAWABQ+0JFgJkFanUbNWHcgqWqZ4qJse6Deo9ACqEgO4ycGDwSKiYuIQk5rScimjAEBIAJngmoejY+MRkBBIAZkpQAGrUomlmJVCS0koA3PqG4NAAMgQA1hAAggByOAC2yDIxvgFBIcgZEdmk42GZkWQS-YOUlPUeGCoSeMBQfaYQvQNKHLOTWVFLxzIWgg5qHIwScH3sUABE9zLvCq94eHAAOZvADkeBUrz2EH+QIgIJ4UHc+k2212+1CR0GACZTgdzgtSFcVjErMI3gBGexadSCZ6vDifak-KEw4EcMEQ6B-AHA+G8bj6IA) as you pointed, but it has drawback in setting `undefined`

Comment: I don't know how to proceed here; unions are not exclusive by nature, if you want exclusivity you have to work at it.  Since `MaybeExclusive` is not exclusive I will disengage unless I see an [edit] that addresses this.  Good luck!

Comment: I understand now. I made an assumption which is wrong, but you can see my goal - to have an exclusion of two types (in 'object' notation) and getting rid of the `unknown` or `undefined`. Is there a trick for it?

Comment: I think maybe I should just avoid thinking about exclusivity at all (and I'll just call your type `MyMaybe` and not worry about it).  If you want to extract the type argument you probably want your conditional type not to be distributive over unions, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WG2n2m). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, kind of. My aim was [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyBDRAjYBRKKaAHgBUA+OAXjgG84A3DAGwFdgAuOUuAXzgA+dRi3ZdSAGjjBC0LgSJQ+AKFCRYCZKkw5gADWgKSFasKZtO3PoOEzF82Ut6rw0eEhTosuA1CNQAVQA7AHcoDDAyShoeUBhgIIATAGczUUsASyCAMxk4ADVrAH4vXX9ifMouIOAGGQBuZRd1dy04PVMdXHLkmCgsgHNyZQBjCCDeuBAuDpp6czE4AHJe-qCBpak7OTgakLh-AAoAShUxifgQACYZ03n0rhW+waWVZrdNTwBNTu99Q0cxFWg2G50miC4PzmIgsj2B6020kc1WA+yOp34AHpMQgABYZVLJXEQVjMRJBJbwELQADWTTUHw8qAAWr9dL5-MEwhFiF9QeNJgAvLismggepAA)

Comment: I guess we can't talk about this without introducing "xor" or "exclusivity" where it doesn't apply.  I'd love to continue but I don't think I can, sorry.